# Old story about two men fighting over a water hole and the alien who tries to make peace between them

Tags: story-identification, aliens, warfare

This story is 40 or 50 years old or more.  There is a drought; the men, normally friends, are fighting over the last water hole because there is only enough water for one of their two families.  An alien comes on the scene; it uses its superior technology to force the two men to stop fighting and listen while it lectures them on the need for peaceful cooperation.  When the alien leaves, the men nod to each other then resume their positions and keep on fighting.

Comment: So the alien just stopped their fighting, and didn't do anything *useful*, like digging another well? Why shouldn't they start fighting again? If there's only enough water for one family, "peaceful cooperation" isn't likely to get them any more water...

Comment: That was rather the point of the story- the alien was a rather KLaatu-like figure who simply spoke as a moral authority, not as a practical expert, who simply stated that the two men simply stop their fighting and co-operate. Bit of a satire on the genre of Superior Alien.

Answer (score 11):

That's ["Or Else"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57509) by Henry Kuttner & C.L. Moore. It has been widely anthologised.